# SFTP not keeping connection alive

Tags: sftp, sublimetext, connection-timeout

I am looking for a way to keep my ftp connection from timing out, if possible keep it open for hours while I work on my projects
In Sublime Text 2 I am using this package "SFTP"

```
https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp
```

When I go to upload a file to my server it usually takes about 30 seconds to reconnect then it uploads the file. If I then immediately save the file again it is instantaneous. I have set the options to keep the connection alive but they don't seem to be working.

**"connect_timeout": 1800,

"keepalive": 1800,**

```
{
    // The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
    // Visit http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings for help

    // sftp, ftp or ftps
    "type": "ftp",

    "save_before_upload": true,
    "upload_on_save": true,
    "sync_down_on_open": false,
    "sync_skip_deletes": false,
    "sync_same_age": true,
    "confirm_downloads": false,
    "confirm_sync": true,
    "confirm_overwrite_newer": false,

    "host": "example.com",
    "user": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "remote_path": "/public_html/example/wp-content/plugins/",

    "ignore_regexes": [
        "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
        "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
        "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
    ],
    //"file_permissions": "664",
    //"dir_permissions": "775",

    //"extra_list_connections": 0,

    "connect_timeout": 1800,
    "keepalive": 1800,
    //"ftp_passive_mode": true,
    //"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
    //"ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
    //"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],

    //"preserve_modification_times": false,
    //"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
    //"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
    //"remote_locale": "C",
    //"allow_config_upload": false,
}
```

Comment: I saw your comment, my previous answer is totally irrelevant.  You will have to contact siteground.com's support about their sftp timeout setting, I suspect that is out of your control and they are unlikely to adjust it...

Comment: OK thanks. What were the attributes you mentioned again, that needed to be changed, or are you saying those were not relevant either?

Answer (score 0):

So this is how it works in my view, the server where you are trying to SFTP into need not support the TCP keep alive. Your client has to implement a keep alive procedure. Only then the modification of this parameter makes some difference from the client side.

- ```
  How it works:
  ```

The keepalive concept is very simple: when you set up a TCP connection, you associate a set of timers. Some of these timers deal with the keepalive procedure. When the keepalive timer reaches zero, you send your peer a keepalive probe packet with no data in it and the ACK flag turned on. You can do this because of the TCP/IP specifications, as a sort of duplicate ACK, and the remote endpoint will have no arguments, as TCP is a stream-oriented protocol. On the other hand, you will receive a reply from the remote host (which doesn't need to support keepalive at all, just TCP/IP), with no data and the ACK set.

If you receive a reply to your keepalive probe, you can assert that the connection is still up and running without worrying about the user-level implementation. In fact, TCP permits you to handle a stream, not packets, and so a zero-length data packet is not dangerous for the user program.

This procedure is useful because if the other peers lose their connection (for example by rebooting) you will notice that the connection is broken, even if you don't have traffic on it. If the keepalive probes are not replied to by your peer, you can assert that the connection cannot be considered valid and then take the correct action (Taken from - [TCP KeepAlive](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html))